# Link in a flash message, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, hyperlink, flash-message

I have the following line in my application which shows flash message with a hyperlink.

```
flash[:danger] = %Q[Click following <a href="#" class="flash_link" id="flash_link" ><strong>link</strong></a> to proceed]
```

Bu rails engine generates following html.

```
<a href="#" class="flash_link"><strong>link</strong></a>
```

Why didn't it generate `id="flash_link"` ?

Any suggestions,

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is not generating `id`? Putting `%Q[Click following <a href="#" class="flash_link" id="flash_link" ><strong>link</strong></a> to proceed]` in the console gave me this `"Click following <a href=\"#\" class=\"flash_link\" id=\"flash_link\" ><strong>link</strong></a> to proceed"`

Comment: I have tried several times. I'm using rails 5, which rails version are you using now ?

Comment: I;m using Rails 5 too

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is not from %Q, I curious with your question, I checked from rails console (as Pavan said it get the result), I also tested with HTML view that rendered by rails with html_safe, I also get the id rendered (probably you can start **to trace how you show "flash message"**

```
<%= (%Q[Click following <a href="#" class="flash_link" id="flash_link" ><strong>link</strong></a> to proceed]).html_safe
```

it rendered

```
<a href="#" class="flash_link" id="flash_link"><strong>link</strong></a>
```

I'm using rails 5.0.2